# Iterating vector of pointers results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming. I am trying to implement a Command design pattern using a vector of pointers to some Command instances.

I can iterate over the vector using another aproach (for example using the index to access every element) but I would like to understand why I get the error.

I asume that vector allocates every element contiguously and that every element has the same size.

```
struct Command {
    virtual void execute(){};
};

struct CommandOne : Command {
    std::string member = "string";
    void execute() override{
        std::cout << member << std::endl;
    }
};

struct CommandTwo : Command {
    void execute() override {
        std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
    }
};

CommandOne commandOne{};
CommandTwo commandTwo{};
std::vector<Command*> commands;

int main (int argc, char** argv){
    commands.push_back(&commandOne);    
    commands.push_back(&commandTwo);    
    Command* ptr_commands = commands.at(0);
    ptr_commands->execute();
    ptr_commands++;
    ptr_commands->execute();
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
string
string
```

But I get:

```
string
segment fault
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: I don't think you can increment the result of `at`, you need to increment an iterator. Consider using [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) if you can.

Comment: Good idea! I am still learning that i why I didnt think of that. Thanks for the advice

Comment: You iterated the raw pointer, which is NOT an iterator or part of an array.

Comment: @RafaelPáezBastida "_I am still learning that i why I didnt think of that._" Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Learning by trial, and error, won't teach you about any amount of possible UB (like the one, you hit here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two `struct` objects here are, for all intents and purposes, located at random positions in memory. The pointer you get back from `at` refers to one of them, and one of them only. They're not necessarily contiguous in memory. Incrementing that pointer is not a valid operation.

The best way to handle this is to iterate over the vector using the venerable `for` loop:

```
for (auto c = commands.begin(); i != commands.end(); ++i) {
  (*c)->execute();
}
```

In newer C++ this might even look like:

```
for (auto c : commands) {
  c->execute();
}
```

You'll also want to consider using new C++ iterator features like [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
for_each(commands.begin(), commands.end(), [](Command* c) { c->execute(); });
```

You'll also want to ensure that anything you allocate with `new` gets properly released with `delete` at some point before program termination. By allocating you assume responsibility for cleaning up. Don't neglect that.

As alter points out in the comments below, `unique_ptr` is a great way of off-loading that responsibility.

Comment: Pushing instances isn't a great option when you need polymorphism. Perhaps `std::unique_ptr<Command>` is what you need?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius In this example they're pretty trivial, but you're right, there may be better ways. Using `unique_ptr` may be one approach.

Comment: @tadman I deleted my comment, because alter put the gist of my comment in a cleaner way. And, even if the current example is trivial, it **does** require polymorphism, so one wouldn't be able to push instances, even having this example, in mind.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I get what you're saying now and I've reworked the answer accordingly. Great points.